# syntax error keyword 'import' react-loadable firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox

right now in my project I'm using react-loadable to code-split the codebase. 
on development environment, it is run fine in chrome browser but when I'm trying to use it on firefox, the console said something like this:

[image]

I found that the error comes from import() function conducted in react-loadable. Something like this:

```
  const LineChart = Loadable({
        loader: () => import ('../js/LineChart' /* webpackChunkName: "CorrectorPerformanceChart" */),
        loading: AppLoader
  });

  /* The problem is in the loader parameter */
```

But this problem only occurs in development, when I built it and serve it, the error is gone.

*What can I do to mitigate this problem? Is there any polyfill or settings that can be used in development? (I'm using create react app)*

firefox version: 61.0.2 (64-bit)

Thank you very much :)

Comment: real ES2016+ `import` statements _have_ to be at the top of the file doing the importing. They're not allowed anywhere else. Once you run it through webpack or rollup or something, that becomes irrelevant, because those bundlers will unroll the imports into plain JS.

Comment: So do i need to use react-loadable in top of my file? Indeed I was using that block of codes inside of the switch statement. I wanted to use dynamic imports

Comment: You don't want dynamic imports, because dynamic imports cannot be bundled. You want to import all the dependencies your code might use, and then let your bundler and minifier make sure that's still a nice compact download. So yes, `import { LineChart } from '../js/LineChart';` at the top (or without `{}` if it uses default exports), and then `loader: LineChart` in your code.

Comment: wow thanks for your answers! :) now I have some inspirations to making my code structures right.